# What is the difference between suspend and hibernate in Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora

I have fedora 13. What is the difference between suspend and resume?
If I suspend, how do I turn on the pc?
If I hibernate, how do I get out of hibernation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suspend stops operation of all applications and puts the machine into a low-power mode. Various triggers can resume the machine, among them pressing a key or quickly pressing and releasing the power button.

Hibernate moves the contents of memory into swap, tells the bootloader to boot directly into the appropriate kernel, and shuts the machine down. You thaw the machine by powering up, which causes the kernel to reload the contents of memory from swap.

Comment: What do you mean by "moves the contents of memory into swap"?

Comment: @PolyShell: I don't know the exact details; you'd need to talk to someone that knows TuxOnIce better than I.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, the difference is where your work-in-progress gets kept.  Suspend puts everything into RAM, and shuts off pretty much everything but what's needed to maintain that memory, and detect startup triggers.  Hibernate writes everything to your hard drive and completely powers down the system.

I imagine the same is true for Linux, as these are common terms.  The process for turning the computer on may vary depending on your selected preferences, but typically the on/off button works regardless.

Answer (score 4):

There is a major difference between suspend and hibernate, suspend saves the snapshot of present system state into ram and your hard-disk power will be turned-off (ram, mother-board, cpu) will be powered on, while when you press the power button it reloads the snap shot saved in ram with in seconds based on the system capability. Coming to the hybernate the present system snapshot will be saved on swap partion, the complete system will be turned off, while when we powered on the machine, it reloads the snap-shot from swap partion little bit faster than regular boot, but slower than suspend.